# Javascript Promise > TypeError: Handling missing images in API Feed

Tags: javascript, json, rest

As a newbie, I honestly don't know if the questions I have reviewed (many) already contain the answer I need. I've totally hacked the code from various articles/resources, so it may not be pretty.

I'm pulling in a REST API feed, and filtering based on the data I need. If there is no image in the JSON feed, the code stops, and this is where I'm stuck. I would like to load a default image (default-image.jpg) when an image is not present in the API feed.

```
var boatHeaders = new Headers();
boatHeaders.append("Accept", "application/vnd.dmm-v1+json");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: boatHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.boats.com/inventory/search?fields=MakeString,Model,ModelYear,NominalLength,NormPrice,BoatLocation,Images&key=x?x?x?x?x?x?x?", requestOptions)
  .then(function (response) {
  return response.json();
})
  .then(function (boatData) {
    loadTableData(boatData);
})
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(`Error: ` + err);
})

function loadTableData(boatData) {
  const boats = Object.values(boatData.results);
  for (let boat of boats) {
    console.log(boat.Images[0].Uri, boat.NominalLength, boat.MakeString + ', ' + boat.Model, boat.ModelYear, boat.NormPrice, boat.BoatLocation.BoatCityName + ', ' + boat.BoatLocation.BoatStateCode);
  }
}
```

Note: I have omitted the API Key for security reasons, and am including the first x3 entries from the JSON (2nd Object has no Image);

```
{
  "BoatLocation": {
    "BoatCityName": "Niantic",
    "BoatCountryID": "US",
    "BoatStateCode": "CT"
  },
  "MakeString": "Pro Line",
  "ModelYear": 2006,
  "Model": "Express",
  "NominalLength": "35 ft",
  "NormPrice": 139900,
  "Images": [
    {
      "Priority": "0",
      "Caption": "Photo 1",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/66/3366166_0_140320111653_1.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T16:53:39-08:00"
    },
    {
      "Priority": "1",
      "Caption": "Motors",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/66/3366166_0_140320111653_2.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T16:53:39-08:00"
    },
    {
      "Priority": "2",
      "Caption": "Helm",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/66/3366166_0_140320111653_3.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T16:53:40-08:00"
    },
    {
      "Priority": "3",
      "Caption": "Seating",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/66/3366166_0_140320111653_4.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T16:53:40-08:00"
    },
    {
      "Priority": "4",
      "Caption": "Forward Berth",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/66/3366166_0_140320111653_5.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T16:53:40-08:00"
    },
    {
      "Priority": "5",
      "Caption": "Dinette",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/66/3366166_0_140320111653_6.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T16:53:40-08:00"
    },
    {
      "Priority": "6",
      "Caption": "Aft Berth",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/66/3366166_0_140320111653_7.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T16:53:40-08:00"
    },
    {
      "Priority": "7",
      "Caption": "Head",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/66/3366166_0_140320111653_8.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T16:53:40-08:00"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "BoatLocation": {
    "BoatCityName": "Greenwich",
    "BoatCountryID": "US",
    "BoatStateCode": "CT"
  },
  "MakeString": "Sea Ray",
  "ModelYear": 2002,
  "Model": "36 DA",
  "NominalLength": "36 ft",
  "NormPrice": 159995
}
{
  "BoatLocation": {
    "BoatCityName": "Greenwich",
    "BoatCountryID": "US",
    "BoatStateCode": "CT"
  },
  "MakeString": "Grady-White",
  "ModelYear": 2005,
  "Model": "",
  "NominalLength": "20 ft",
  "NormPrice": 29995,
  "Images": [
    {
      "Priority": "0",
      "Caption": "Photo 1",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/68/3366168_0_140320111820_1.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T18:20:17-08:00"
    },
    {
      "Priority": "1",
      "Caption": "Photo 2",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/68/3366168_0_140320111820_2.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T18:20:18-08:00"
    },
    {
      "Priority": "2",
      "Caption": "Photo 3",
      "Uri": "https://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/61/68/3366168_0_140320111820_3.jpg",
      "LastModifiedDateTime": "2011-03-14T18:20:18-08:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the working loadTableData function using the solution I approved.

```
function loadTableData(boatData) {
  const boats = Object.values(boatData.results);
  //console.log(boats)
  for (let boat of boats) {
    const defaultUri = "default-image.jpg";
    let img = defaultUri;
    if (boat.Images && boat.Images[0] && boat.Images[0]) {
      img = boat.Images[0].Uri;
    }
  console.log(img, boat.NominalLength, boat.MakeString + ', ' + boat.Model, boat.ModelYear, boat.NormPrice, boat.BoatLocation.BoatCityName + ', ' + boat.BoatLocation.BoatStateCode);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Images` field can be `undefined`, you should see whether `Images` property is defined or not.

```
for (let boat of boats) {
  const defaultUri = "default-image.jpg"
  const img = boat.Images && boat.Images[0] && boat.Images[0].Uri || defaultUri
  // do something with img
}
```

You can use if statements instead of '&&' operators.

```
for (let boat of boats) {
  const defaultUri = "default-image.jpg"
  let img = defaultUri
  if (boat.Images && boat.Images[0] && boat.Images[0].Uri) {
    img = boat.Images[0].Uri
  }
  // do something with img
}
```

Comment: Why `&& boat.Images[0] && boat.Images[0]`? This is redundant

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

`console.log( boat.Images[0] ? boat.Images[0].Uri : "default-image.jpg")`

which is called a ternary operator. It's the condensed form of :

```
if(boat.Images[0]){
   console.log(boat.Images[0].Uri);
} else {
   console.log("default-image.jpg")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time in getting back and offering a solution. I went with @c0m1t as it was the first in the list.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I don't have enough kudos >> 
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

add `if condition` if get an image from api set this image else add your image

```
    if(boat.Images[0].Uri==null||boat.Images[0].Uri==undefind){
         console.log("default image ")
    }
else{
    console.log(boat.Images[0].Uri)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time in getting back and offering a solution. I went with @c0m1t as it was the first in the list.

Comment: This code will break if `boat.Images[0]` is undefined. You're not checking for its existence first.